# Reference a child relationship record in SOQL query

Tags: soql

There is a requirement to have a new record created on the Product2 object when the current product2 record meets a certain criteria. These records should then be linked together.

I have used process builder to create a new product2 record in the product2 object when the current product2 record meets a certain criteria. On the new product2 record I have a lookup field that is populated with the historic product2 record Id.

If I want to reference the new product2 record, from the historic product2 record, how would I do this? The lookup field is called Historic_R&D_Record__c and has a child relationship name of "Services".

I need to reference the historic product record in the soql query below.

```
List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List <Opportunity>();
listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId,Name,Owner.FirstName,(SELECT Id,       Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems
                                                            WHERE Product2.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Initiated__c = FALSE)
                                                            FROM Opportunity
                                                            WHERE Id in
                                                                       (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                                                        WHERE Product2.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Initiated__c = FALSE)];
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at with this "new Product"/"historic product" business. Can you clarify the architecture? You need to know the API Name of the parent object and the child object, and the API Name of the relationship between them (lookup from child).

Comment: @AdrianLarson is that a bit more clear?

Comment: A bit, yes. But why use `SOQL` at all? When creating the new `Product2` record, you have the `Id` of the old one readily available. Just set the lookup during creation?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I give the historic ID to the new record using process builder, that part is easy enough, but how do I give the new product record ID (which hasn't yet been created) to the historic record?

Comment: Ah, I see now. You could use a separate process on insert that updates that parent record? What is the other relationship name that you are populating already?

Comment: It won't allow me to do that as it creates a circular dependency @AdrianLarson therefore is there a way I can do this in the SOQL query, or would you suggest creating a junction object so I can access both records easily?